# Correct require path perl

Tags: perl, path, require

I have a perl script `myscript.pl` and configuration file `myscript.conf`. Both are in same directory and I have included the conf in `myscript.pl` by `require 'myscript.conf';`

If I run myscript like `./myscript.pl` , it works fine. If I run with full path like `/full/path/myscript.pl` it raises an error

`Can't locate myscript.conf in @INC`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It's just an issue with path. I don't think code is relevant here.

Comment: @Harikrishnan this is not the most effective way to ask for help. Showing code would be an advantage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is not because you are using the full path when you run the program, but because the *current working directory* is different from the location of the script. The current directory `.` appears in `@INC` so perl will always look there for modules, but the current directory has to be correct for it to find them.

The canonical way of adding a library location that is relative to the location of the script itself is with the [`FindBin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html) module, like this

```
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;

require 'myscript.conf';
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
use lib '/full/path/'
```

At the begining of your program. This will add the path to `@INC`

Comment: Alternatively, one can use `PERL5LIB=/full/path/ /full/path/myscript.pl` instead of editing the file.

Comment: I cannot determine the full path. The user can deploy the script in any directory and run it.

Comment: @Harikrishnan So you should add a shell script which changes the directory before running the program.